# Javascript password length

Tags: javascript, forms, passwords

I'm a newbie to javascript. I have a signup form that requires a password and a password confirmation. So far, I'm able to properly verify whether the passwords match. However, I have attempted to insert a minimum length on the password and it is not working. What is wrong with my code?

```
 <HTML>
    <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="formpassword" required placeholder="Password" class="formpassword form-control" id="form-password" nickname='Password'>
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="form-password-confirm">Password Confirm</label>
                                <input type="password" name="formpasswordconfirm" required placeholder="Password Confirm" class="formpassword form-control" id="form-password-confirm" nickname='Password Confirm'>
                                <div id='passwordmsg' class="id-msg"></div>
                              </div>
    <HTML>
    <JS>
    $('#form-password').on('change', function(){
    pass = $('#form-password').val();
    if(pass < 6){
        $('#passwordmsg').html('Password must be at least 6 characters');
    }else {
        $('#passwordmsg').html("");

});


$('#form-password-confirm').on('change', function() {
    pass = $('#form-password').val();
    pass_confirm = $('#form-password-confirm').val();
    if(pass != pass_confirm){
        $('#passwordmsg').html("Password mismatched");
    }else{
        $('#passwordmsg').html("");
    }
    set_btn_enable();
});
    </JS>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
    if(pass < 6){
```

You want to have:

```
     if(pass.length < 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if the string is lesser than 6, you should use the length property of the string, so instead of

```
if(pass < 6) ...
```

should be

```
if(pass.length < 6) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` returns the value in the specified field. That'd be `hunter42` or whatever the user's entered for their password, which means you're doing `'hunter42' < 6`, which makes no sense.

```
[..snip...].val().length;
                 ^^^^^^^
```

to get the LENGTH of the returned field value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to control the length of the password with:

```
...
pass = $('#form-password').val();
if(pass.length < 6){
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You done one small mistake.

In if conditions Check the **length of value** instead of giving only string value.

```
$('#form-password').on('change', function(){
pass = $('#form-password').val();
if(pass.length < 6){
    $('#passwordmsg').html('Password must be at least 6 characters');
}else {
    $('#passwordmsg').html("");

});
```

Use length property to get number of characters(length of a string). [For more refer this link.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp)